# Is there a fast way to get all elements from any collection/map that match one of a list of conditions?

Tags: java, indexing

I'm trying to build a search function for a game so users can see creatures of one type (species, gender, and status effects like health and energy).  This searching would be running so-frequently-it's-almost-constantly, so it needs to be as optimized as I can make it.

I could use maps, sets, arrays, whatever.  I'm willing to change most of the rest of the program to make this flow smoother.  My current strategy is a bunch of HashMaps trying to act as easily searched indexes, instead of iterating through every single creature in the ranch.  I've spent 2 days reading about far too many Map and List variations, but none of them seem to give me the power to quickly check each item in list A to see if it contains a member of list B.  Is such indexing possible in Java, or should I just give up on indexing and iterate the big object and check all the conditions at once?

I'm pretty sure I did it entirely wrong but I remember y'all like to see the bad code for context so here it is:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Creature> creatures = new HashMap<Integer, Creature>();
public static HashMap<Integer, Species> species = new HashMap<Integer, Species>();
public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> gender = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> health = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> energy = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
public static void newCreature (Creature creature) {
    creatures.put(indexPos, creature);
    species.put(indexPos, creature.species);
    gender.put(indexPos, creature.gender);
    health.put(indexPos, creature.health);
    indexPos++;
}
public static void searchBy(EnumSet<Species> speciesInclude, boolean[] genderInclude) {
Integer[] index = creatures.keySet().toArray(new Integer[0]);
    if (!speciesInclude.isEmpty() && speciesInclude != EnumSet.allOf(Species.class)) {
        for (Integer i : index) {
            if (!speciesInclude.contains(species.get(i))){
                //remove element from array
            }
        }
    }
    if (genderInclude[0] != genderInclude[1]) {
        for (Integer i : index) {
            if (genderInclude[gender.get(i)]) {
                //remove element from array
            }
        }
    }
    //TODO check against health
    //TODO check against energy
    //TODO check against more things
}
```

Why yes, I *am* totally new to Java and think in a PHP/SQL way.

Comment: *"HashMaps trying to act as easily searched indexes, instead of iterating through every single creature in the ranch"* Aren't you doing that anyway? Iterating through `creatures` key set.

Comment: I assumed that the keyset (Integers) would be lighter than the actual collection of Creature objects (fairly large/complex objects).  If not, then my question becomes academic.

Comment: If you're trying to optimize, the limiting factor is going to be sheer number of creatures. You could reduce the number of tests by e.g. mapping creatures to their traits, like maybe you have a `Map<Species, List<Creature>>`. It looks like you're trying to use maps to look up fields of each creature which is pretty pointless. A hash lookup is slower than a field access.

Comment: *"should I just give up on indexing and iterate the big object and check all the conditions at once?"* There's mainly one way to find out: try it and see. Iterating a big list is the easiest to implement and if it performs sufficiently then you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: The edit you suggested is done, complete, and working already.  Spent 2 days trying to find a 'better' way to do this sort of thing...  I think the short answer to my question is "Why would you want to?"  or alternatively "No, this is not a database program."

Answer (score 0):

No one posted this in answer form so I will to get it off the 'unanswered' list:

No, Java is not a database program so there is no JOIN-like options.  It is much faster to iterate through the objects and check their fields - not a difficult operation in Java.

If there is one category that is often being searched, one can store the objects in separate lists, eg: Map>, but the simple approach is a good one.  Thanks, Radiodef, for the help.